# Div on Div with img element

Tags: html, css

I want my Div `id="b"` to be **on** the other Div `id="a"`, but instead I get the Div `id="b"` under Div `id="a"`, What need I change in the Css?

**Html:**

```
 <div class="picad30">
   <div class="pic_sin30" id="a">
       <img width="110" border="0" class="pic_sin30" src="SMALLAD.png"/>
   </div>
   <div class="picgar30 p" id="b"></div>
   <div >
       <div >upload</div>
       <div ></div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

**Css:**

```
.picad30{
    width:130px;
    float:right;
    display:table;
    margin: 20px 0 0 0px;
    position: relative;
}

.pic_sin30{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 87px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 130px;
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
}

.picgar30{
    background-position:-5px -244px;
    cursor:pointer;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    float:left;
    z-index:20;
    position:absolute;
}

.p {
    background-image: url("PIC/icon.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Can you be more clear?

Comment: Sorry, this makes no sense.

Comment: I edited the question to clearer

Comment: From what you're asking, this is a question of HTML markup, not CSS. Do you want one `div` within the other?

Comment: @MelanciaUK, no, I want the Div to be **on** the other div, and because the first div has an element of img, I can't manage it with the position css.

Comment: Got it. I was a bit confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
.p {
   background-image: url("PIC/icon.png");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   z-index:2;
   position:absolute !important;
   top:0;
   left:0;
}
```

It can be helpful to you [Read this](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/)

**Edit**

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k2LJc/)

Answer (score 0):

So I've made a few updates to your code and I hope I've interpreted your question correctly. Am I right by saying you want to stack `.pic_gar30 or id=b`  on top of `.pic_sin30 or id=a`? And then on top of `.pic_gar30` you want to add an icon?

If this is correct I've done the following, I've wrapped your 2 image divs in a parent div called pic-container which has the height you wish to use on your images and position relative so you can absolutely position your images inside without the upload text hiding in behind also.

You want to use the same css on both your image holders so I've given both of them the class img-holder and applied styles that position absolute, since `.pic-gar30 comes after .pic_sin30 it will automatically be positioned on top`. But if you like you can add a z-index to .pic_gar30. I've then used the ::after psuedo class selector http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-class-selectors/ on .pic_gar30 in order to position your icon above the image.

**Please see my example which I hope helps http://jsfiddle.net/LXaCT/**